# Rep suddenly dropped

Tags: support, reputation

My rep has just dropped 40 points so I'm guessing one of my answers with some votes against it was deleted (or possibly a question I had an answer against?)

Is there any way of finding out what this was?

Comment: It's also possible that some user who upvoted you was deleted. I'm not sure under what conditions the rep would be taken away, but I don't think you can see who it was or on what posts.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh, that is a possibility I hadn't thought of

Comment: It could be a serial upvoting reversal. Mods can see some voting pattern it if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Vincent, I was just reading about that: http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3331/serial-voting-reversed-meaning-and-response apparently I would have received a notification if that was the case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Happy to explain:
The user who posted [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/50676/prevent-sexual-manipulation) specifically asked for moderator help in having it deleted. It was also generating some rather ugly comments. I chose to defer to the OP  in this case, even if it led to a rep loss for the answers.

If you disagree with the deletion (for instance if you think the answers are valuable despite the question being severely down-voted and closed) I believe you should have enough rep to vote to undelete, or otherwise (moderator deletion might be difficult to undo) flag it or continue the discussion here.

Comment: That would explain it. I shall also defer to the asker in that case.

Comment: @Separatrix, again, deleting questions w/ exiting answers is not something I would normally do, but I felt the specific situation called for it. Thank you for your understanding!

Comment: Couldn't you have just disassociated the question with the account instead of deleting it? I've had a mod do that for me once. And the comments could have been stopped via locking the question...

Comment: @Aify when a post is valuable to the site but the author wants to delete it, mods will ask for disassociation.  (Mods can't do it directly; we have to request it from SE.)  If a question is closed and can't be fixed and reopened, though, that's a harder sell, so sometimes mods will just delete in that case.  It's a case-by-case assessment.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that if a (current) diamond moderator is involved in the deletion of a post, the community cannot undelete it. Anyone with at least the 10k required to see the deleted post can, though, flag it for moderator attention and ask for it to be re-reviewed. Or bring it up on the site's Meta in particular, drawing the attention of other high-rep site users to it and that way convincing a moderator to undelete.

Answer (score 1):

If you click the icon that my lovely red arrow points to...

[image]

...You can see rep changes at a glance. For a more detailed view navigate (only apparently on the main site, not the meta page?) to your profile, and click the "reputation tab"

[image]

Comment: That only tells you rep changes by vote, deletions are silent in terms of notification

Comment: @Separatrix Is this specific to World Building? Because I know on Stack Overflow I get notifications when things like users (who gave me votes) are deleted.

Comment: I don't have any rep to speak of anywhere else so I don't have experience otherwise.